# Adding Pointers and Change Value

Tags: c, pointers

I have a code:

```
int double(int *x) {
    *x = (*x) + (*x);
    return *x;
}

int main() {
   int i = 10;
   int j;
   j = double(&i);
   printf("i= %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
   return 0;
```

}

The output is i = 20, j = 20. 
Why does the value of i change?

Comment: Because you wrote `*x = (*x) + (*x);`.

Comment: Your compiler allows you to use `double` as a function name, really?

Comment: this is the first reverse question I've ever heard. People often ask about why the value doesn't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are passing a pointer to i to the double function, which allows it to change it's value.  This is known as "pass by reference".  If you had just used ints instead of pointers, the value of i would not have changed. This is called "pass by value".

Answer (score 0):

The output of `i` is changed, because you have written `*x = (*x) + (*x);` in your function `double`, which you call with `j = double(&i);` Therefore it will be `x = x + x` with `x = 10`, which is `20`.

If you send a pointer, you are allowing the contents of that `int` to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
j = double(&i);
```

You are passing address of i, so double function can change it's value.

If you could have passed like,

```
j = double(i);
```

Value of `i` will remain unchanged.